# How to give alert before deleting the row from gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp-classic, modal-dialog, modalpopupextender

Hi im having a modal popup extender for user confirmation to delete a file in gridview. I have given delete image button on the gridview.on delete button click in every row of grid the control is passed to rowcommand function based on the command name of the image button. Before the control passes to rowcommand, it has to display an alert to delete "Do you want to delete?" if yes it has pass control to row command,if no it should not delete.

Thanks in advance.

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            try
            {
                int selectedrow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                mpedeleteMessage.Show(); // here im displaying the popup confirmation.
              //on Ok click it has to proceed further in below code else it has to exit
```

further code...

Comment: please show us your code, what the expected results are, and any error messages so we can help

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Comment: No. I havent solved.Without giving alert.Im able to delete (by clicking delete image button the control is passed to gridview rowcommande based on command name).Have to give alert before deleting.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is you modal popup used as a confirmation of the deletion of the file?

If yes, then you could call deletion of the file from the modal popup instead of the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

@ravi - I would comment, but don't have 50 rep yet. 
You may not wish to use modal.popup as my understanding is that chromium amd firefox will be phasing out this function and other browsers will likely follow suit. Could you use windows.open (parent - child) instead? I use this very successfully throughout my application.